# How to get real filename from wget

Tags: bash, filenames, wget

I am writing a bash script and using wget to retrieve some PDF files form a website.  For example:

```
wget www.barb.co.uk/news/item-subscriber/id/213/index.html
```

But wget saves the file as index.html.  If I am in a browser and enter that URL, it correctly downloads the file with it's real name - "BARB Bulletin 25 - December 10.pdf".

How can I get wget to do the same?  Or is there another way I can find the real name of the file (from within a bash script)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `--content-disposition` option to make wget have a more sophisticated look into the headers of the HTTP response, which helps in most cases.

Example:

```
wget --content-disposition www.barb.co.uk/news/item-subscriber/id/213/index.html
```

Comment: You can make this the default by adding `content_disposition=on` to a `~/.wgetrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at wgets `--content-disposition` option.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your valuable input. That certainly helps a lot. Especially since there is no link in the answer...

Comment: love the sarcasm, but it's a scripted answer put in by SO.  If you want the detail I meant you were only putting in a reference to an item without helping to explain how it might be used or why it would be the solution.  hoeni did this and you missed out.

Comment: What’s to explain? You add the switch to the `wget` command. Done.